# Assigning value to a variable only if argv specified in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am new to the TCL scripting .I have a script called "Sample.tcl". In the Sample.tcl I have a variable called `$name`. How can I assign a value to the variable if there exist a specific argv i.e.

```
Sample.tcl -step xyz
```

Only if I specify `-step` then `$name` should be `xyz`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You are on the right track with argv. Have you tried using `set` in the script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `$name` might be in this context (it's a *really* unusual name for a variable, and using variable variable names is typically a bad idea) but under the guess that you're trying to set `step` to `xyz` in this case, you can put this in your script:

```
apply {{} {
    # For each pair of values in the arguments (after the script name)
    global argv
    foreach {key value} $argv {
        # Safety-check: if the key starts with a hyphen...
        if {[string match -* $key]} {
            # ... strip the leading hyphen(s)
            set varname [string trimleft $key "-"]
            # ... bind that global var name to a local name
            upvar 1 $varname var
            # ... and set the variable to the value we've got.
            set var $value
        }
    }
}}
```

It's done in an `apply` so that we don't pollute the global namespace with all our working variables (`key`, `value`, `varname` and `var`) and because we don't really need to make a procedure for something we're only going to do once.

This isn't a *safe* piece of code, not by any means, but it is a useful and flexible way to get something working.

---

In general, parsing command line arguments can take quite a bit of thought to get perfectly right and there's various packages to help out, but that's only really important when writing code for other people to run. When it's just for yourself, you can be a lot sloppier and get the job done in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `cmdline` package from tcllib you could write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

package require cmdline

set options {
    {step.arg       ""      "Set the step value"}
}

try {
    array set params [cmdline::getoptions argv $options]
} on error e {
    puts stderr $e
    exit 1
}

if {$params(step) ne ""} {
    set name $params(step)
}

if {[info exists name]} {
    puts "name = $name"
} else {
    puts "name is not set"
}
```